# click function needs 2 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 tabs and depending on which tab is click I want the form action to change.
I have this:

```
$('#myTab li').click(function(){
    if ($('#action1').hasClass('active')){
        $('#my-form').attr('action', '/order/signup1')
    }
    else if ($('#action2').hasClass('active')){
        $('#my-form').attr('action', '/order/signup2')
    }
    else if ($('#action3').hasClass('active')){
        $('#my-form').attr('action', '/order/signup3')
    }

});`
```

Is actually happening is that the first changes the action to the wrong form action, then the second click corrects the form action.

I need this to be correct form the first click.

Comment: `myTab` is not a valid selector. Care to share the HTML as well..?

Comment: You have `<myTab>` and `<action1>` elements?

Comment: You'll need to encode it manually using a counter with if/else or a switch. The format is quite simple once you've done it once.I can elaborate if you dont get the point in my comment..!

Comment: Sorry I've updated my code. They are ids (it's slightly edited from my actual code)

Comment: @Andy : can you give a fiddle? and show your HTML as well please....

Comment: @Andy What tabs are you using? are they jquery UI tabs or your own implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ..depending on which tab is click I want the form action to change.

There could be a more simple way to do this, but because you are not giving us your HTML, I can't be sure. Anyway, you don't need the `active` class here. You can just use the `id` of the clicked element like this: `this.id`

Here's the code:

```
$('#myTab li').click(function(){
    if (this.id === 'action1'){
        $('#my-form').attr('action', '/order/signup1');
    }
    else if (this.id === 'action2'){
        $('#my-form').attr('action', '/order/signup2');
    }
    else if (this.id === 'action3'){
        $('#my-form').attr('action', '/order/signup3');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8v8070eh/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because you code runs first and the 'active' class is not set yet. One of the things you could try is to wrap you code in a setTimeout().

```
$('#myTab li').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('#action1').hasClass('active')){
            $('#my-form').attr('action', '/order/signup1')
        }
        else if ($('#action2').hasClass('active')){
            $('#my-form').attr('action', '/order/signup2')
        }
        else if ($('#action3').hasClass('active')){
            $('#my-form').attr('action', '/order/signup3')
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

This should at least help you to determine if it's caused by your code running 'too quickly'